# Creating a string Dataframe column that is a splice of an existing column in the Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my current Dataframe I have a string column. I would like to make a new column that is a slice of that original string column but am running into this error message:

> SettingWithCopyWarning:
>   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
>   Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"

Below is my code. The first part is a function I have created to create the string splice, and the second part of the code is the creation of the new Dataframe column by applying the function to the "Title" column. The column "Title" is simply a string data type.

```py
    def clean_up(name):
            for i in name:
                product_name = i.split()
                new_names = product_name[0:3]
                company = " ".join(new_names)
                return company

    top_100["Company"] = top_100["Title"].apply(clean_up)
```

Can someone please help me figure out a different way to achieve this and avoid the error? Thank you!

Comment: It is a `warning`, not an `error`. The program should still run & give you the output. If you can add your input & expected output as text, the community can suggest  easier/faster ways to get the output you desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map the string function using `map`.
Notice all of your functionality is in my lambda function

`top_100['Company'] = top_100['Title'].map(lambda x: ' '.join(x.split(' ')[:3]))`

I aggregated the 3 lines in your for loop with `x.split(' ')[:3]`

Comment: Would be nice if you'd add some explanation about the code

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using pandas.Series.str methods

```
top_100=pd.DataFrame([[" UVW   CV",12345],
                       ["TCR FLOW zoom",3452],
                      ["Make Me Rich please",9873]],columns=["Title","some number"])
top_100['Company']=top_100["Title"].str.split().apply(lambda x: x[0:3]).str.join(" ")
top_100
```